# Java Logback, Log specific code flow into a separated file

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm working with Spring Logback and I need to Log onto a separated file but only a specific call of a function (a specific flow/process). The problem is that this function calls many other internal functions and instances a few classes and all of those have their own Logs, I want to know if there is a way I can contain all those logs that start with the call of that function into a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate logger for those functions using `getLogger("something"). In the configuration file you can direct logger "something" to a separate file.